# Obtaining LRR and BAF values from affymetrix SNP array

Tags: arrays, r, windows, bioinformatics

I am trying to extract the `LRR` and `BAF` values from an affymetrix SNP chip without success using linux based tools. I tried to use a small subset in windows designed software called `Axiom™ CNV Summary Tools Software` and it works perfectly. The problem is that I have a huge dataset and would be impossible to run in windows machine powerful enough.

Let´s expose my steps until this point. First, I obtained five tab delimited files which are require to linux and/or windows pipeline (1-3 obtained with APT affymetrix software).

1 - The Axiom `calls.txt` or genotype file:

```
   calls <- 'probeset_id    sample_1    sample_2    sample_3
    AX-100010998    2   2   2
    AX-100010999    1   0   1
    AX-100011005    0   1   2
    AX-100011007    2   2   1
    AX-100011008    1   1   2
    AX-100011010    2   2   2
    AX-100011011    0   1   0
    AX-100011012    0   1   0
    AX-100011016    0   0   1
    AX-100011017    0   0   2'
calls <- read.table(text=calls, header=T)
```

2 - The `confidences.txt` file:

```
conf<- 'probeset_id sample_1    sample_2    sample_3
AX-100010998    0.00001 0.0002  0.00006
AX-100010999    0.00001 0.00001 0.00001
AX-100011005    0.00007 0.00017 0.00052
AX-100011007    0.00001 0.00001 0.00001
AX-100011008    0.001   0.00152 0.00001
AX-100011010    0.00001 0.00001 0.00002
AX-100011011    0.00004 0.00307 0.00002
AX-100011012    0.00001 0.00001 0.00001
AX-100011016    0.00003 0.00001 0.00001
AX-100011017    0.00003 0.01938 0.00032' 
conf <- read.table(text=conf, header=T)
```

3 - The `summary.txt` file:

```
summ <- 'probeset_id    sample_1    sample_2    sample_3
AX-100010998-A  740.33229   655.41465   811.98053
AX-100010998-B  1139.25679  1659.55079  917.7128
AX-100010999-A  1285.67306  1739.03296  1083.48455
AX-100010999-B  1403.51265  341.85893   1237.48577
AX-100011005-A  1650.03408  1274.57594  485.5324
AX-100011005-B  430.3122    2674.70182  4070.90727
AX-100011007-A  411.28952   449.76345   2060.7136
AX-100011007-B  4506.77692  4107.12982  2065.58516
AX-100011008-A  427.78263   439.63541   333.86312
AX-100011008-B  1033.41335  1075.31617  1623.69271
AX-100011010-A  390.12996   350.54456   356.63156
AX-100011010-B  1183.29912  1256.01391  1650.82396
AX-100011011-A  3593.93578  2902.34079  2776.2503
AX-100011011-B  867.33447   2252.54552  961.31596
AX-100011012-A  2250.44699  1192.46116  1927.70581
AX-100011012-B  740.31957   1721.70283  662.1414
AX-100011016-A  1287.9221   1367.95468  1037.98191
AX-100011016-B  554.8795    666.93132   1487.2143
AX-100011017-A  2002.40468  1787.42982  490.28802
AX-100011017-B  849.92775   1025.44417  1429.96567'
summ <- read.table(text=summ, header=T)
```

4 - The `gender.txt`:

```
gender <- 'cel_files    gender
sample_1    female
sample_2    female
sample_3    female'
gender <- read.table(text=gender, header=F)
```

And finally the map file `map.db` in windows (non readable) or `map.txt` in linux as follows:

```
map <- 'Name    Chr Position
AX-100010998    Z   70667736
AX-100010999    4   36427048
AX-100011005    26  4016045
AX-100011007    6   25439800
AX-100011008    2   147800617
AX-100011010    1   98919397
AX-100011011    Z   66652642
AX-100011012    7   28180218
AX-100011016    1A  33254907
AX-100011017    5   1918020'
map <- read.table(text=map, header=T)
```

This is my result in **windows based result** for `sample_1`:

```
Name    Chr Position    sample_1.GType  sample_1.Log R Ratio    sample_1.B Allele Freq
AX-100010998    Z   70667736    BB  Infinity    0.675637419295063
AX-100010999    4   36427048    AB  0.101639462657534   0.531373516807123
AX-100011005    26  4016045 AA  -0.111910305454305  0
AX-100011007    6   25439800    BB  0.148781943283483   1
AX-100011008    2   147800617   AB  -0.293273363654622  0.609503132331127
AX-100011010    1   98919397    BB  -0.283993308525307  0.960031843823016
AX-100011011    Z   66652642    AA  Infinity    0.00579049667757003
AX-100011012    7   28180218    AA  0.0245684274744242  0.032174599843476
AX-100011016    1A  33254907    AA  -0.265925457515035  0
AX-100011017    5   1918020 AA  -0.0091211520536838 0
```

The values from the windows based tool seems to be correct, but in linux output that´s is not the case. I am following the steps decribed at penncnv software (http://penncnv.openbioinformatics.org/en/latest/user-guide/input/) and I log2 transformed my `summary.txt` and did the quantile normalization with `limma` package using `normalizeBetweenArrays(x)`, finishing with the `corrsummary.txt`:

```
      corrsum <- 'probeset_id  sample_1  sample_2  sample_3
    AX-100010998-A  9.804932  9.285738  9.530882
    AX-100010998-B 10.249239 10.528922  9.804932
    AX-100010999-A 10.528922 10.641862 10.134816
    AX-100010999-B 10.641862  8.472829 10.249239
    AX-100011005-A 10.804446 10.249239  8.816931
    AX-100011005-B  8.835381 11.186266 12.045852
    AX-100011007-A  8.542343  8.835381 11.039756
    AX-100011007-B 12.045852 12.045852 11.186266
    AX-100011008-A  8.816931  8.816931  8.472829
    AX-100011008-B 10.134816  9.910173 10.592867
    AX-100011010-A  8.472829  8.542343  8.542343
    AX-100011010-B 10.374032 10.134816 10.641862
    AX-100011011-A 11.593784 11.593784 11.593784
    AX-100011011-B 10.012055 11.039756  9.910173
    AX-100011012-A 11.186266 10.012055 10.804446
    AX-100011012-B  9.530882 10.592867  9.285738
    AX-100011016-A 10.592867 10.374032 10.012055
    AX-100011016-B  9.285738  9.530882 10.528922
    AX-100011017-A 11.039756 10.804446  8.835381
    AX-100011017-B  9.910173  9.804932 10.374032'
corrsum <- read.table(text=corrsum, header=T)
```

Thus I applied:

```
 ./generate_affy_geno_cluster.pl calls.txt confidences.txt corrsummary.txt --locfile map.txt --sexfile gender.txt --output gencluster
```

and

```
 ./normalize_affy_geno_cluster.pl --locfile map.txt gencluster calls.txt --output lrrbaf.txt
```

And my **linux based result** (`lrrbaf.txt`) which must contain `LRR` and `BAF` information looks like that:

```
output <- 'Name    Chr     Position        sample_1.LogRRatio    sample_1.BAlleleFreq  sample_2.LogRRatio    sample_2.BAlleleFreq  sample_3.LogRRatio    sample_3.BAlleleFreq
AX-100010999    4       36427048        -1952.0739      2       -1953.0739      2       -1952.0739      2
AX-100011005    26      4016045 -2245.1784      2       -2244.1784      2       -2243.1784      2
AX-100011007    6       25439800        -4433.4661      2       -4433.4661      2       -4434.4661      2
AX-100011008    2       147800617       -1493.2287      2       -1493.2287      2       -1492.2287      2
AX-100011011    Z       66652642        -4088.2311      2       -4087.2311      2       -4088.2311      2
AX-100011012    7       28180218        -2741.2623      2       -2740.2623      2       -2741.2623      2
AX-100011016    1A      33254907        -2117.7005      2       -2117.7005      2       -2116.7005      2
AX-100011017    5       1918020 -3067.4077      2       -3067.4077      2       -3065.4077      2'

output <- read.table(text=output, header=T)
```

As showed above the linux result is completely different from windows based results (and make much less sense) and additionally do not contain the `GType` column in the `output`. Sorry to compose such a long question, but my intention was to make it as reproducible as possible. I would be grateful for any light to solve this problem as well any important remarks about this kind of data that I maybe forgot.